# Simple effect processing in AudioKit example for MacOS files needed

Tags: macos, audio, audiokit

I have a unique filter that I want to use while playing Audio files on MacOS and am trying to start based on an AudioKit example whereby I just replace a current effect with new code with my filtering. However, I can't find an example that is close to what I want and the amount of effort required to do from scratch is a bit too much. Is anyone aware of such examples that I can use? I've looked through all of the examples on AudioKit they either just play audio files or have effects but assume microphone data. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the Developer directory of AudioKit you'll find an example called "ExtendingAudioKit" which is probably going to be your best template for how to set up a project that uses AudioKit for the base, but allows you to develop custom DSP external to AudioKit.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for long delay. That wasn't much help because I was looking more for an example to modify than a template. Still too much stuff to figure out there for me